# How to save selected dropdown list item into sql database table

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

My dropdown list items populated from the database table and working fine and want to save the selected dropdown list item into another sql database table but saving only value (id) instead text. Somebody helps me to solve these problems.

I have tried below codes but save only id instead save text

Model:

```
public class BiodataSingle
{
   public BiodataSingle()
   {
       this.MDA = new List<SelectListItem>();
       this.ZoneDept = new List<SelectListItem>();
   }

   public List<SelectListItem> MDA { get; set; }
   public List<SelectListItem> ZoneDept { get; set; }
   public int MDAId { get; set; 
   public int ZoDepId { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult AjaxMethod(string type, int value)
{
        BiodataSingle model = new BiodataSingle();

        switch (type)
        {
            case "ddlmdaName":
                model.ZoneDept = (from z in this._context.ZoneDept
                                  where z.MDAId == value
                                  select new SelectListItem
                                  {
                                      Value = z.ZoDepId.ToString(),
                                      Text = z.ZoneDeptname
                                  }).ToList();
                break;
        }
        return Json(model);
}

[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> SaveBiodata(BiodataSingle biodataSingle)
{
       if (ModelState.IsValid)
       {
           var newbiodata = new BiodataViewModel()
           {
               MDA = biodataSingle.MDAId,
               Department = biodataSingle.ZoDepId,
           };

           await _context.BiodataA.AddAsync(newbiodata);
           await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
       }
                              
       return View(biodataSingle);
```

}

View:

```
<select id="ddlmdaName" name="MDAId" asp-for="MDAId" asp-items="Model.MDA" class="form-control">
         <option value="">--Please select--</option>
</select>
<select id="ddlzoneDept" name="ZoDepId" asp-for="ZoDepId" asp-items="Model.ZoneDept" class="form-control">
        <option value="">--Please select--</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Not an answer, but please please use better names for your methods, variables, etc. and use a good naming convention.

Comment: I am new into the forum. The above codes are highlights to be considered to assisting me. because the selected dropdown list is saving into the database but saving only ID instead to save Name of the MDA. I need to save Name of MDA if I click save button.

Answer (score 1):

If I don't misunderstand your question, When you select an option and submit the form, In controller you can only get the value(Id), But you want to get the text, right? I hope this simple demo can help you.

When your dropdown list items populated from the database, You can use `TempData["xx"]` to pass data between actions.

```
//.....other code.....
BiodataSingle model = new BiodataSingle();
//populate from database
 model.MDA = xxxx;
 model.ZoneDept = xxxx;

//then use TempData["xx"] to save the value
TempData["MDA"] = JsonSerializer.Serialize(model.MDA);
TempData["ZoneDept"] = JsonSerializer.Serialize(model.ZoneDept);
//....other code.....
```

Then in `SaveBiodata` action, You can select text by value in TempData["xxxx"]

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> SaveBiodata(BiodataSingle biodataSingle)
{
       if (ModelState.IsValid)
       {
           List<SelectListItem>? MDA= JsonSerializer.Deserialize<List<SelectListItem>>(TempData["MDA"].ToString());

           List<SelectListItem>? ZoneDept= JsonSerializer.Deserialize<List<SelectListItem>>(TempData["ZoneDept"].ToString());

           //Then you can select the corresponding text by value(Id)

           var MDAName= MDA.Where(x => x.Value == biodataSingle.MDAId).Select(y => y.Text).FirstOrDefault();

           var ZoneDeptName= ZoneDept.Where(x => x.Value == biodataSingle.ZoDepId).Select(y => y.Text).FirstOrDefault();

          //Now you have got the name
          //.....other code......
       }
                              
       return View(biodataSingle);
}
```

**Or**, If you don't need the ID to do any action, You can just:

```
select new SelectListItem
     {
           Value = z.ZoneDeptname,
           Text = z.ZoneDeptname
     }
```

Set both Value  and b
Text to name, Then you can get name directly in the backhand.

Answer (score 0):

Change your dropdown markup to be like:

```
<select id="ddlzoneDept" name="ZoDepId" asp-for="ZoDepId" asp-items="@(new SelectList(Model.ZoneDept , "ZoDepId", "ZoneDeptname"))" class="form-control">
        <option value="">--Please select--</option>
</select>
```

I am using this way, and it is working.

Comment: Thanks Xinran Shen and Waleed.alhasan for your efforts to assist me I decided to post another question that will carry a details explanation in this way members can clearly understand my problem.